# Jbuilder rendering within HTML Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jbuilder

For some reason my feature branch is now rendering my json endpoints within html, which is breaking anything trying to use them.

An example request would log something like this previously:

```
Rendering api/user/settings/show.json.jbuilder
Rendered api/user/settings/show.json.jbuilder
Completed 200 OK
```

But now looks like:

```
Rendering api/user/settings/show.json.jbuilder within layouts/user
Rendered api/user/settings/show.json.jbuilder within layouts/user
Rendered partials/_footer.haml
Completed 200 OK
```

What seems to be causing this is the `layout "user"` in the controller it inherits from. What's strange is this previously did not affect it.

Rails 5.0.1

I have a fix in now that just adds `layout false` to API controllers, but I'd like to know what the cause of it is.

Comment: sounds like a regression, have you checked the rails issues?

Comment: I thought it'd be something like that, but my Gemfile.lock didn't even change. I tried looking for an issue in jbuilder but I'll double check Rails too

Comment: Here's a potentially related issue but looks like it's relatively inactive https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14173

Comment: ah ok, it sounded like you updated rails. in that case it's more likely that you introduced the issue yourself. did you use git bisect to find a commit that introduced this behavior?